# XSLT - convert elements to attributes and include an element from sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to convert an XML file using XSLT to achieve the following:

Convert all elements of a node to attributes of that node and include an element outside of the node within the node.

The make it a bit more clear I'll lead with an example.
My initial XML file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<queryResponse type="InventoryDetails" rootUrl="https://10.30.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data"
    requestUrl="https://10.30.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data/InventoryDetails?.full=true&amp;.firstResult=0&amp;.maxResults=1000"
    responseType="listEntityInstances" count="13" first="0" last="12">
    <entity url="https://10.30.0.192/webacs/api/v1/data/InventoryDetails/521521"
        type="InventoryDetails" dtoType="inventoryDetailsDTO">
        <inventoryDetailsDTO id="521521" displayName="521521">
        <deviceId>541541</deviceId>
        <ethernetInterfaces>
             <ethernetInterface>
                    <accessVlan>815</accessVlan>
                    <adminStatus>DOWN</adminStatus>
                    <allowedVlanIds>ALL</allowedVlanIds>
                    <desiredTrunkingEncapsulation>NEGOTIATE_OR_BEING_NEGOTIATED</desiredTrunkingEncapsulation>
                    <desiredVlanMode>ACCESS</desiredVlanMode>
                    <duplexMode>FULLDUPLEX</duplexMode>
                    <macAddress>6c:99:89:45:a4:8d</macAddress>
                    <mtu>1500</mtu>
                    <name>GigabitEthernet1/0/13</name>
                    <nativeVlan>1</nativeVlan>
                    <operationalStatus>DOWN</operationalStatus>
                    <operationalVlanMode>DOWN</operationalVlanMode>
                    <pruneEligibleVlanIds>2-1001</pruneEligibleVlanIds>
                    <speed>
                        <instanceId>0</instanceId>
                        <instanceVersion>0</instanceVersion>
                        <longAmount>1000000000</longAmount>
                    </speed>
                    <trunkingEncapsulationNegotiation>false</trunkingEncapsulationNegotiation>
                </ethernetInterface>
                <ethernetInterface>
                    <accessVlan>1</accessVlan>
                    <adminStatus>UP</adminStatus>
                    <allowedVlanIds>6,11</allowedVlanIds>
                    <desiredTrunkingEncapsulation>_8021Q</desiredTrunkingEncapsulation>
                    <desiredVlanMode>TRUNK</desiredVlanMode>
                    <duplexMode>FULLDUPLEX</duplexMode>
                    <macAddress>6c:99:89:45:a4:92</macAddress>
                    <mtu>1500</mtu>
                    <name>GigabitEthernet1/0/18</name>
                    <nativeVlan>1</nativeVlan>
                    <operationalStatus>UP</operationalStatus>
                    <operationalTrunkEncapsulation>_8021Q</operationalTrunkEncapsulation>
                    <operationalVlanMode>TRUNK</operationalVlanMode>
                    <pruneEligibleVlanIds>2-1001</pruneEligibleVlanIds>
                    <speed>
                        <instanceId>0</instanceId>
                        <instanceVersion>0</instanceVersion>
                        <longAmount>1000000000</longAmount>
                    </speed>
                    <trunkingEncapsulationNegotiation>true</trunkingEncapsulationNegotiation>
                </ethernetInterface>
                <modules>
                <module>
                    <description>Switch 2 - WS-C3750X-48 - Fixed Module 0</description>
                    <equipmentId>546563</equipmentId>
                    <equipmentType>MODULE</equipmentType>
                    <operationStatus>ok</operationStatus>
                    <physicalLocation>WS-C3750X-48</physicalLocation>
                    <productName>Switch 2 - WS-C3750X-48 - Fixed Module 0</productName>
                    <softwareVersion>15.0(2)SE7</softwareVersion>
                    <vendorType>cevModuleCat3750x48</vendorType>
                </module>
                <module>
                    <description>FRULink 10G SM Module</description>
                    <equipmentId>546565</equipmentId>
                    <equipmentType>MODULE</equipmentType>
                    <operationStatus>ok</operationStatus>
                    <physicalLocation>FRULink Container</physicalLocation>
                    <productName>Switch 2 - FRULink Slot 1 - FRULink Module</productName>
                    <softwareVersion>15.0(2)SE7</softwareVersion>
                    <vendorType>cevC3KxSm10g</vendorType>
                </module>
            </modules>
            </ethernetInterfaces>
        </inventoryDetailsDTO>
    </entity>
</queryResponse>
```

And my outcome would need to be the following:

```
<Data>
  <ethernetInterface deviceID="xxx" accessVlan="xxxx" adminStatus="xxxx"/>
  <ethernetInterface devideID="xxx" accessVlan="xxxx" adminStatus="xxxx"/>
</Data>
```

And this basically for each node within the `<entity>` node and all the attributes.
While I can get some data to format properly I either get too much (it only formats what I specify and the rest is still copied but not formatted) and also the `DeviceID` you see is not within the node that I'm getting the attributes from but in a separate sibling node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this is as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/queryResponse">
    <Data>
        <xsl:for-each select="entity/inventoryDetailsDTO/ethernetInterfaces/ethernetInterface">
            <ethernetInterface deviceID="{../../deviceId}">
                <xsl:for-each select="accessVlan | adminStatus">
                    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ethernetInterface>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Data>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note**:

1. XML is case-sensitive; `deviceID` is not the same as `deviceId`;
2. The `deviceId` is not in a "separate sibling node"; it is in an "uncle" (a child of grandparent) node. Having your input XML properly indented can be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for the starting point, it was actually almost exactly what I needed. I changed the   <xsl:for-each select="accessVlan | adminStatus"> in to  <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*[not(*)]"> so I can get all my attributes and works like a charm. Also thnx for the Note's :) I considered it a sibling node since it was side by side  to the >ethernetInterfaces>, my Indentation was just copied from what notepad++ gave me..

Comment: As a supplymentary question, If I would like to do the same for the "Modules" but within the same transformation, can I just copy the entire thing and put it underneath (but still within <Data></Data> or do I need to adjust it completly? If I must adjust fully then I might consider doing multiple transformations. (this since I have other outputs that might be similar)

Comment: I believe you can do the same. Eventually, to avoid code repetition, you could have a single template matching all nodes you want to treat the same way.

Comment: Right.. And I could do that by just doing a select="template1 | template2". Great! Marked as answer!